# Ubuntu 18.04 broken python3-disupgrade

Tags: python

I am a first time Ubuntu user and I think I did something wrong..
When I try to install or uninstall something it goes like this:

```
dpkg: warning: old python3 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 5: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
```

And:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core : Depends: python3-distupgrade (= 1:18.04.29) but 1:18.04.28 is installed
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk : Depends: python3-distupgrade (= 1:18.04.29) but 1:18.04.28 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How can I fix this? Is there a solution for this?
Up until this moment I tried everything I can find on Google about his problem..

Comment: What do you get after `sudo apt install -f`?

Comment: Exactly what were you trying to do to your version of Python3? And how were you trying to do it?